# Error: Missing $ inserted when using kable

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex, kable

I am attempting to output a latex table using `r markdown`, `kable`, and `kableExtra`. I needed to use conditional logic to add colors to my table with cell_spec. But with the pdf output, it shows latex code as follows;

[pdf output with latex code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tduBP.png)

If I add `escape = false` in `kable()`, it gives me the following error,

> ! Missing $ inserted.  
>                   $ l.142 sepal_
>               length & sepal_width & petal_length & petal_width & Species\  Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:  14185 strings
>   out of 492970  208670 string characters out of 3125261  323511 words
>   of memory out of 3000000  17834 multiletter control sequences out of
>   15000+200000  23725 words of font info for 40 fonts, out of 3000000
>   for 9000  1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191 
>   41i,9n,38p,1027b,272s stack positions out of
>   5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

I'm new to `rmarkdown` and [latex](/questions/tagged/latex), please help me to solve the issue. Thank you.

This is my rmd file code:

````
---
title: "Iris Data Table"
output: pdf_document
header-includes: \usepackage [table]{xcolor}
geometry: margin = 1cm
params:
  n: NA
  datafile: "//ad.monash.edu/home/User076/vbed0001/Documents/IRIS.csv" #always set the absolute full path
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, message=FALSE}

d <- read.csv(params$datafile, header = TRUE, sep = ",")

# this uses to remove the warning messages from the pdf file
library(memisc, warn.conflicts = FALSE, quietly=TRUE)

# the package order is important, always kableExtra at the top
#options(kableExtra.latex.load_packages = FALSE)
library(kableExtra)
library(magrittr)
library(formattable)
library(dplyr)
library(knitr) 
library(devtools)


options(knitr.table.format = "latex")

if(params$n == "set"){
dtset <- d %>% filter(Species == "setosa")

dtset <- d %>% filter(Species == "setosa")

dtset %>%
 mutate(
   sepal_length = cell_spec(sepal_length,format = "latex",background = (ifelse(sepal_length>4.5,"#D3D3D3","#ff0000")))

 )%>%
 kable(format = "latex",caption = "Setosa Table")%>%
   kable_styling(position = "center",bootstrap_options = "bordered")


}


```
````

Comment: Try to use other column names without the underscore. E.g transform the using `gsub("_", "\\_", names(data))`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer, it worked well. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error is a result of having underscores "_" in your dataframe. In this case, the column names contain underscores. In TeX this symbol is used to set subscripts in math environments. This is why it has to be escaped (`\_`) when used in normal text. Remove, escape or replace the underscores with e.g.

```
names(data) <- gsub("_", "", names(data))    # remove
names(data) <- gsub("_", "\\_", names(data)) # escape
names(data) <- gsub("_", " ", names(data))   # replace with space
```

Comment: One thing I did is, using `dplyr::rename_all` I defined `esc.us <- function(nm) { gsub("_", "\\\\_", nm) }` then piped the data table as follows: `data %>% rename_all(esc.us)`. There may be a better way, but it seems to work.

Comment: @steveb, the newer `tidyverse`/`dplyr` approach would be to use `replace_with`

Comment: @climatestudent thanks for adding that update! I will have a look as this seems like it could be a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I need to remove the underscore from the chunk name.

For example, this works:

````
```{r summaryTableBaseline, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
summaryTableBaseline %>%
    kable(col.names = c("Docker Image", "Min", "Mean", "Median", "Max"),
          caption = "Baseline Benchmark") %>%
    kable_styling()
```
````

But this does not work:

````
```{r summary_Table_Baseline, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
summaryTableBaseline %>%
    kable(col.names = c("Docker Image", "Min", "Mean", "Median", "Max"),
          caption = "Baseline Benchmark") %>%
    kable_styling()
```
````

Answer (score 1):

#### General solution for underscores anywhere in the data

Building on the good comment by @steveb, I generalized the solution so it can not only work on column names (as `replace_all` does).

```
data %>% map_df(~ gsub("_", "\\_", .x))
```

Explanation:

1. The `purrr::map` processes every table cell for that.
2. The `purrr::map_df` puts the result into a dataframe
3. As argument, `purrr::map` accepts a function for which the `purrr` shortcut is `~` and the function argment is `.x` (for every element)